# Multiple Audio Files In One ViewController With Button

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, swift5

Want to play multiple audio files in the same `ViewController`. When a user clicks on `Button1` the `file1.mp3` should be loaded into `ViewController` and when user hit play same should play and for `button2 file2.mp3` should load and play.

I know how to do this for a single file but for multiple files I have to create `ViewController` again and again which is so hard. This is my code for single file

```
 @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if player.isPlaying {

        player.stop()
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"play.png"),for: .normal)
    } else {
        player.delegate = self
        player.play()
         player.numberOfLoops = 107
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"pause.png"),for: .normal)
    }


 }


 do {
     let audioPlayer = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "chalisa", ofType: "mp3")
     try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPlayer!) as URL)
 }catch {
   //ERROR
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tableview List all songs Name and Play Button use to Multiple audio files use in one viewcontroller

```
import AVFoundation

//MARK:- Variable Declaration
var player: AVAudioPlayer?    

func playMusic() {
     guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "chalisa", withExtension: "mp3") else { return }

do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)            
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)


    player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)

    /* iOS 10 and earlier require the following line:
    player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3) */

    guard let player = player else { return }

    player.play()

} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
}
```